# How to use a dynamic value for elements' background color?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I want to be able to change app's theme, even when the app has launched.

So I defined a resource:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBrush" Color="#AAAAAA"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

used it across the app:

```
<... Background="{StaticResource AppBrush}" .. />
```

and I'm able to changed it in `App`'s constructor:

```
((SolidColorBrush)Resources["AppBrush"]).Color = color;
```

Now I can change it fine, but user has to relaunch the app to changes take effect. I can't use last line of code somewhere inside the app I get a memory error.

How can I change app's theme from inside of the app and see changes?

Comment: hasn't someone a solution for this? :)

Answer (score 0):

The error happened because AppBrush resource defined in App.xaml, and you want to access it from outside App.xaml using the same code. You have to change the code slightly to explicitly telling application to find the Resource in App.xaml :

```
((SolidColorBrush)App.Current.Resources["AppBrush"]).Color = color;
```

Without doing that, application will end up searching for AppBrush resource in current page then failed to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone does not support DynamicResource unfortunately.  So you have 2 options:

1) just accept the restriction and require a relaunch
2) bind the content (whatever that might be, grid background, button, etc) to a viewModel property that returns a color.  then you can change the color and call the notifypropertychanged to get the UI to update straight away.

Let me know if you are unclear about how to implement (2).